# Token transfer missing_auth_exception

Tags: smart-contract, testnet, transfer

[image]

```
{
"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error",
"error":{"code":3090004,"name":"missing_auth_exception",
"what":"Missing required authority",
"details":[{"message":"missing authority of thomsoimj21","file":"apply_context.cpp","line_number":151,
"method":"require_authorization"},
{"message":"pending console output: ","file":"apply_context.cpp",
"line_number":72,"method":"exec_one"
}]}}
```

I am not able to transfer token from one an account to  aother account.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not authorized transaction by providing private key of account thomsoimj21 and as I said earlier please try to read full documentation to avoid these small errors.